# Summing downloaded data by IP addresses

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this file:

```
2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:30:46 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44
2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:30:46 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:32:15 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66643
88.222.10.7 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66643
88.222.10.7 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
88.222.10.7 - - [18/Sep/2011:13:45:39 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
88.222.10.7 - - [19/Sep/2011:05:47:35 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66643
88.222.10.7 - - [19/Sep/2011:05:47:36 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
121.141.172.40 - - [19/Sep/2011:20:32:07 +0300] "CONNECT 64.12.202.43:443 HTTP/1.0" 405 235
```

And I have IP addresses data (last number in each line), for example `44, 1406, 66643, 6664, .....`

I want to sum all data that belongs to same IP address. So my results should be:

```
2001:778:0:1::21      68093    (44+1406+66643)
88.222.10.7           136098   (66643+1406+66643+1406)
121.141.172.40        235      (235)
```

Is is possible to do that in shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the desired output:

```
# awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{arr[$1]+=$10}END{for(i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' file
88.222.10.7 136098
2001:778:0:1::21 68093
121.141.172.40 235
```